# Error in R h2o.find_threshold_by_max_metric

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o

I'm using h2o v3.10.4.6 version with R. Built a DL Binomial classification model using `h2o.deeplearning()` function, would like to find some thresholds using this function `h2o.find_threshold_by_max_metric()`. However I got error like this:

> Error in h2o.find_threshold_by_max_metric(NNmodel, "F1") :    No F1
>   for H2OBinomialModel

I use [this documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/h2o/versions/3.10.4.6/topics/h2o.find_threshold_by_max_metric) as reference, but there is no examples

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Please edit the post to include a reproducible code example, thanks. (Much easier to debug this way).

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `H2OBinomialModel` into `find_threshold_by_max_metric`, you're supposed to pass `H2OBinomialMetrics` instead, for example:

`p <- h2o.performance(NNmodel)
h2o.find_threshold_by_max_metric(p, "F1")`

`h2o.performance` does take some more parameters which you might need to set.

I'm not sure but I thought `F1` isn't supported for deeplearning, should that be the case please try one of `logloss, auc, classification_error, rmse`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mateusz ! You are right, I need to get the model performance to get the respective thresholds of metrics:

Here is the model performance, so the metrics showing are the ones I can get from h2o.find_threshold_by_max_metric() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
perf_oot <- h2o.performance(NNmodel, newdata=oot_data.hex)
```

Comment: Maximum Metrics: Maximum metrics at their respective thresholds
                        metric threshold    value idx
1                       max f1  0.463273 0.904095 250
2                       max f2  0.000980 0.952198 398
3                 max f0point5  0.990303 0.901456  14
4                 max accuracy  0.556570 0.839004 214
5                max precision  0.999478 0.962611   2
6                   max recall  0.000025 1.000000 399
7              max specificity  0.999981 0.918722   0